# Creating a View on table create in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have been looking into how to create a pre defined view on a table every time it is created within SQL Server.

A nightly job truncates the database and recreates the schema so I would be looking to create the view then. I know the table name and the structure so I though this is possible.

The way I have been trying to achieve this is though DDL triggers but I cant seem to get it working. Any help or steer on what to look at next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to tag your database brand, I suppose MS SQL. Also, if your are recreating whole database, also triggers are dropped.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the change now

Comment: recreates ALL schema? or just tables? If just tables, leave your view alone, and it will work once the table is there again. If it drops the views as well, then just script out the view, and have that script run in the same routine that recreates the rest of your schema.

Comment: Why not add it as a step in the nightly process ?

Comment: i was trying to avoid that as I wanted it to be at the point of creation but I think I will have to go down that route.

Comment: @daveb if the code is right after table creation, it is effectively done at the point of creation. There is really no benefit to creating code based on triggers.